# Custom routes inside shared template

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, twig, template-engine

Lets say I have two controllers that work with the same entity, and use the same set of templates. Every template is supposed to generate buttons/forms/links with URLs to actions of controller that generated this template. So basically, the only thing that is different in the templates are the URLs generated.

You can imagine the problem like a admin CRUD controller with a `newAction` and `editAction`, which use the same template, but form actions must differ. My case is more complicated than that, though.

I considered following:

- Setting the routes from the controller, but it feels like a lot of code that is out of place.
- Different set of templates. Seems like anti-DRY and a lot of reused code.
- Using template inheritance, where base template is the one with all the HTML, and child templates only contain the links, but it feels really hacky.

Is there a clever approach to solve this problem?

**EDIT**: My problem is not generating CRUD. This is more of a "best-practice" question.

I encountered this problem while implementing something like a eshop cart with tons of javascript logic bound to it. It appears twice: in the website, and in a iframe, used by some other devices (iPads and stuff). Both carts have to look the same, but because of different logic, the links must lead to different URLs.

What I ended up doing for now is having 2 templates

The one with all the markup, **cart.html.twig:**

```
{% set edit_cart_item = path('edit_cart_item') %}
{% set remove_cart_item = path('remove_cart_item') %}
...html...
<a href="{{ edit_cart_item }}">Edit item</a>
...more html...
```

The one for usage in iframe, **public_cart.html.twig:**

```
{% extends 'MyCartBundle::cart.html.twig' %}
{% set edit_cart_item = path('public_edit_cart_item') %}
{% set remove_cart_item = path('public_remove_cart_item') %}
```

Does the problem have some better solution in all the fancy OOP principles?

Comment: Don't see clearly the problem, can you put some code? the structure of this part of your project too ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a 'clever' approach really.  Why not just use the specified Doctrine command to generate it for you, and then go from there?  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

`php app/console generate:doctrine:crud` with various options

That will get you a solid base done in an 'appropriate' manner, and then you can perform your customizations.

**EDIT:**

After reading your updated post, I would have a look at this:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form

So, if you'd like, you can handle the logic of which form to display by passing in options to the form, and then setting the target via `setAction()`:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route'))
;
```

By design, Symfony gives you a lot of flexibility in how to do things.  A good reference of their best practices for forms can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html

I also think what you're doing is just fine.  When I have complex cases for forms I like to create a Twig template just for the form itself, and then include that in my other templates.  In that template you can pass the target route to it if you'd like, and then you'd just have one form template.

Comment: It is not about crud generation, my case is a little more complicated than this. Check the edited question :)